# SQL REPLACE value based on position in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a column where the values are all in this format '###-##-#-##-##-###-##-#' I need to format all of the values to where the 2nd to last hyphen is replaced with a period '###-##-#-##-##-###.##-#'

Can I use REPLACE based on the position in the string?

Example would be changing '068-27-0-40-12-012-00-0' to '068-27-0-40-12-012.00-0'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in sql server, use the STUFF method to get your work done.

SELECT STUFF('###-##-#-##-##-###-##-#', 19, 1, '.');

First parameter - character expression 
Second parameter - starting from nth position
Third parameter - no of positions to be replaced
Fourth parameter - string to be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support `left()` and `right()` (and in those that don't you can use `substr()`/`substring()` to the same effect).  So:

```
select left(col, 19) || '.' || right(col, 4)
```

Your database may prefer a different concatenation operator/function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select left([ColumnName], 19) + '.' + right([ColumnName], 4);
```